# Can´t add files to VS2017 setup project

Tags: setup-deployment

I'm trying to create an installer project in VS2017.
But I can not add some files to desktop user's folder, like users manual, pdf's and other ones.

Any comments?
Thank you!

[image: Desktop folder]
[image: solution folders]

I triyed add->file but it seems to no responds, no error message...